# border-image transparency bug in IE11

Tags: transparency, internet-explorer-11, css

I'm using the `border-image` property on elements with an image file set as the border background. The border image file has transparency and it works as I want it in Chrome and Firefox.

However, in IE11, the transparent area "overwrites" the background image under the border. Is there a way to fix it? I'm using the same border image on elements with various background images so I'd rather not create separate non-transparent border images for each one.

This is what I have so far:

```css
body {
background: #000;  
}

div {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dzt1.jpg);
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf544.png) 14 round;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

#### Rendering comparison

[image: Comparison]

border-image file:

[image: border-image file]

background-image file:

[image: background-image file]

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: I'm trying to post it but it gives me error :/ "An error occurred submitting the edit." I can't even post it here, in this comment. I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a `border-image-width` instead of `border-width` solves the issue in IE11. If you want to set a fallback, `border-style: dashed` seems to offer more consistent behaviour.

This seems like buggy behaviour but is maybe a simple difference in browser behaviour:

- In Chrome, the `border-width: 14px` *adds 14px each side* and occurs *without* a `border-style`. The `border-style` has no affect when `border-image-width` is set.
- In IE11, the `border-width: 14px` does not add 14px each side *unless* a `border-style` is set. The `border-style` does affect the positioning of the `border-image`, but only when set to `solid`.

#### Screenshot from IE11

[image: Screenshot IE11]

#### Working Example

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dzt1.jpg);
  border-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf544.png) 14 round;  
  border-image-width: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks. And thanks for making my question look better. Writing in english isn't my best skill :)