# Using border-image (with slice) in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

What I have is working spiffingly in Chrome and at the moment I have alternative CSS in place for other browsers (box-shadow instead) using IE and Firefox specific media queries to cater for each one individually (bit of a faff but necessary).

I have tried to use css3pie to get the border-image to work as I know it was not supported by IE, which worked a little (fill didn't work) but only up to IE10 using the IE Emulation .

I read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26058929/border-image-transparency-bug-in-ie11) that border-image is now supported on IE11 but I can't get it to work. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
#header_right{
            border-width: 20px 0 20px 0;
            border-image: url(../../img/bordernew.png)50 0 50 0 repeat;
            -webkit-border-image: url(../../img/bordernew.png)50 0 50 0 repeat;
            -moz-border-image: url(../../img/bordernew.png)50 0 50 0 repeat;
            border-image-slice: 50 0 50 0 fill;
            border-image-width: 20 0 20 0;
            }
```

I made a snippet from when I was originally trying to do it on Chrome - the syntax is a little different (classes instead of ID etc.) but the effect is the same - all good in Chrome, nothing in IE11.

It's not the end of the world as like I said I have alternatives in place, but I'd really like it to appear consistently on all browsers if possible.

Any help appreciated, I've already tried everything I can think of and everything that has already been suggested on here and in every Google result I could find.

Thanks

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://s27.postimg.org/7uqejz1sz/mad_scientist.jpg");
}
.border {
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/uau8kjl4d/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  -webkit-border-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/uau8kjl4d/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  -moz-border-image: url(http://s28.postimg.org/uau8kjl4d/bordernew.png) 50 0 50 0 repeat;
  border-image-slice: 50 0 50 0 fill;
  border-image-width: 20 0 20 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" style="text-align:center;">
  <br />
  <span class="p">Coming soon...</span>
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - finally fixed simply by adding `border-style:solid`! Works in Firefox with that too!